# This program prints "hello" instead of "Hi". How?

Tags: c

Below is the program for if and else

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    float a = 0.7; //a declared as float variable

    if(a == 0.7)  //why it takes only integral part of 0.7 
    {
        printf("Hi"); 
    }
    else
    {
        printf("hello"); 
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

Shouldn't this program display `Hi` instead of `hello` as 0.7 is equal to 0.7?

*(I'm new to C programming)*

Comment: Don’t compare the float variable using == , because the precision of the floating point is not same. You can find plenty of questions in SO regarding floating point comparison.

Comment: Don't compare floating point number like this, [use something like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/what-is-the-most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison)

Comment: Please see [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) and [Why Are Floating Point Numbers Inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate)

Answer (score 6):

Note that

```
float a = 0.7;
```

converts a `double` value `0.7` to a `float` and then

```
if(a == 0.7)
```

converts `a` to a `double`.

Since `0.7` cannot be exactly represented in floating point, the `float` and `double` representations are not quite the same.

You can force the compiler to stay with `float` like this

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float a = 0.7f;
    if(a == 0.7f)
    {
        printf("Hi"); 
    }
    else
    {
        printf("hello"); 
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

And now the program prints "Hi" because it is comparing like with like.

---

More generally you must be very wary of floating point comparisons for equality

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double d = 2.1;
    d /= 3.0;
    if(d == 0.7) {
        puts("Equal");
    }
    else {
        puts("Unequal");
    }
    printf("%.17f\n", d);
    printf("%.17f\n", 0.7);
    return 0; 
}
```

Program output

```
Unequal
0.70000000000000007
0.69999999999999996
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change datatype of **a** to **double**, it'll print hi,
This is because constants in floating point stored in **double** and non floating in **long**, 
double  precision is high and float has less precise, double value stored in 64 bit binary and float value stored in 32 bit binary, it'll be completely clear if you see  the method of floating point numbers conversion to binary convertion.